# PowerShell: Export-CSV doesn't write String[] to file

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, csv, export

I have a problem with exporting three values to a csv.

This is my code:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $sn.Name | 
Where-Object { 
    $_.Description -like "BASP Virtual Adapter" -or
    $_.Description -like "HP Network Team #1" } | 
Select-Object PSComputername, MACAddress, IPAddress | 
Export-Csv C:\Server_MAC_IP.txt -Force
```

without the Export-CSV it is displayed correctly, one name one MAC and one IP, but in the txt it says i.e. "Server01","MAC1","System.String[]".
Is there a way to get the IP address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $sn.Name | 
Where-Object { $_.Description -like "BASP Virtual Adapter" -or $_.Description -like "HP Network Team #1" } | 
Select-Object PSComputername, MACAddress, @{N="IPAddress";E={ $_.IPADDRESS -JOIN ';'}} |
Export-Csv C:\Server_MAC_IP.txt -Force
```

Comment: @IronGibbet Glad to help! The `-join` is needed in case some NIC have more than one IP configrated.